# How do I correct heteroskedasticity using gls and the weights command in R?

Tags: r, regression

I have a model of income that looks like this:

```
income.ols <-lm(INCOME~EDUC+EXPER+EXPER2+EDUC:EXPER+FEMALE+UNION+NONWHITE)
```

and using White's test, I have found evidence of heteroskedasticity. How do I correct it using gls?
I keep getting the same results as the original model, and I know it has something to do with the 'weights' command, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to put it. Any help with this would be great!

Comment: Check out the ridiculously named `sandwich` package, which works directly with the output of your `lm`, and can correct for heterogeneous variance.

Comment: This may not be the right forum to ask this question (stats.stackexchange.com may yield better responses). However, I would recommend that you use a robust regression that could take care of the heteroskedasticity. [link](Check out this http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/rreg.htm). It should walk you through how to run robust regressions.

Comment: OLS assumes constant variance and it can be factored out. If it is different  by observation, it is possible to add a weight vector of the same length so as to make the variance constant. For example, if a variable causes an issue, weights=1/var might be an option. Or you may preprocess your variables before they are fit into the model - centering/scaling would be popular.